# if we're at default and no other options were chosen, do nothing. if were back at default from other options, do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, logic

I have a default value of 2 `var items = [2]` and click events that changes the value from 2 to 3 back and forth depending on the click. since the default value is 2, when the user clicks on the 2 option in the li nothing should happen(that's what i want) because no changes need to be made. only if the user clicked  any other option, they will be able to click the 2 option to use the 2 functionality (well they will be able to click it but no functionality will occur). I guess I need help with logic

```
      $(document).ready( function(){
        var items = [2]
        $('ul  > li > span').on('click', function(e){

            if($(this).siblings("ul").is(":visible")){
                $(this).siblings("ul").slideUp("fast")
            }else{
                $(this).siblings("ul").slideDown("fast")
            }

        })
        $('ul.adding li ul li').on("click" , function(e){
            if($(e.target).hasClass('twoItems')){
                if(items[0] !== 2){
                    //this is messed up
                    items[0] = 2
                    $('.output').append(items[0])
                }else{
                    $('.output').append(items[0])
                }

            }
            if($(e.target).hasClass('threeItems')){
                items[0] = 3
                $('.output').append(items[0])
            }
            console.log(items)

        })
        $('.output').append(items[0])


    });
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class = "adding">
        <li><span class = "span">Add</span> <ul>
            <li class="twoItems">Two Item</li>
            <li class = "threeItems">three items</li>
        </ul></li>

    </ul>
</div>

<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `else` statement from within`$('ul.adding li ul li').on("click"` handler

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var items = [2]
  $('ul  > li > span').on('click', function(e) {

    if ($(this).siblings("ul").is(":visible")) {
      $(this).siblings("ul").slideUp("fast")
    } else {
      $(this).siblings("ul").slideDown("fast")
    }

  })
  $('ul.adding li ul li').on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('twoItems')) {
      if (items[0] !== 2) {
        items[0] = 2
        $('.output').append(items[0])
      }

    }
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('threeItems')) {
      items[0] = 3
      $('.output').append(items[0])
    }
    console.log(items)

  })
  $('.output').append(items[0])


});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="adding">
    <li><span class="span">Add</span> 
      <ul>
        <li class="twoItems">Two Item</li>
        <li class="threeItems">three items</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>

<div class="output"></div>

<div class="output"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="adding">
    <li><span class="span">Add</span> 
      <ul>
        <li class="twoItems">Two Item</li>
        <li class="threeItems">three items</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>

<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer i was just going over your snippet. its good at where it says "Two Item" you click on it before clicking the 'three items' and nothing happens. and when you click on the other  item the 3 comes up. that's good. but when i click on "Two Item" again i want the 2's to appear in output. i see your editing it would be like 2322222223322 only 1 "2" shows up at a time. sorry